# creating dynamic roles using cancancan gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

So I came across this problem at work that I need to make the roles dynamic. On the `cancan` gem they said that I must create predefined roles inside the `User` model like this 
`ROLES = %i[admin moderator author banned]` but we removed it since we wanted to create it on the fly. we only have one role `Admin` and then this admin can create roles. Now here's are an awesome problem. On our `ability.rb` file we have this.

```
 def initialize(user)
      clear_aliased_actions

      # override cancan default aliasing (we don't want to differentiate between read and index)
      alias_action :delete, to: :destroy
      alias_action :edit, to: :update
      alias_action :new, to: :create
      alias_action :new_action, to: :create
      alias_action :show, to: :read
      alias_action :index, :read, to: :display
      alias_action :create, :update, :destroy, to: :modify

      user ||= Spree.user_class.new

      if user.respond_to?(:has_spree_role?) && user.has_spree_role?('admin')
        can :manage, :all
      else

        user.models.pluck(:key).each do |m|
          can :manage, m.constantize
        end

      end
```

so what I did is like this. Since `can` method takes 2 arguments, an action, and a Model, so I created a `models` table that has a many_to_many relationship with `Role`. my problem is that this code especially the else part, some of the model work some of it doesn't, another problem is. Let's say we create another model right a developer will have to go to the console to this. `Model.create(name: 'Newmodel', key:'NamepsaceModelaname')` this is hella weird. can you suggest another way of doing it? or a gem that can do a dynamic role.

Comment: I don't think CanCanCan really is the right tool for the job here. Its good for the simple stuff but not much else. Its a DSL that lets you declaratively write the authorization rules for your application. If you have admins that are dynamically creating roles and setting the access levels for each role thats not declarative and its one of those cases where you will just struggle against a really limiting DSL. I would go for Pundit instead which is just plain OOP. But first I would ask myself if you really need this feature.

Comment: Its going to be a lot of work, and if your not building something like a CMS or some large enterprise system you can get by with having a smart set of roles created as a developer concern.

Comment: @max thank you for your response. Yes, we just had a meeting and this is required by our specification. Since this is internal use and we have multiple departments and users have their privilege. we are also building on top of [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) that's why I'm getting a hard time to create this feature.